# Display Image without loosing quality

Tags: c++, image, qt, qml, splash-screen

I am using QSplashScreen to display a splash screen for my QtQuick 2 application. I am using a decent quality image (838 X 500). It displays correctly in some screen resolutions. But for some other resolutions like 2K resolution, it looks like some low quality transformation is applied.

Already tried Qt::SmoothTransformation

Connecting my laptop to my monitor (I have 2K monitor) and selecting 'Duplicate display' option in display management, produces low quality image. Selecting 'Second screen only' produces decent quality image.

```
QPixmap pixmap(qApp->applicationDirPath()+"/splash.png");
QSplashScreen splash(pixmap.scaledToWidth(screen_width*0.35,Qt::SmoothTransformation));

splash.show();
```

Is there a way to display an image without loosing the quality? 
I am experiencing the same issue with 'Image' in QML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Qt is attempting to render the image at the same "physical" size on a higher resolution display, then it will have no choice but to upscale the image. You should provide a higher resolution image:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#loading-files-depending-on-platform

> The target platforms might automate the loading of alternative
>   resources for different display densities in various ways. On iOS, the
>   @2x filename suffix is used to indicate high DPI versions of images.
>   The Image QML type and the QIcon class automatically load @2x versions
>   of images and icons if they are provided. The QImage and QPixmap
>   classes automatically set the devicePixelRatio of @2x versions of
>   images to 2, but you need to add code to actually use the @2x
>   versions:
>
> ```
> if ( QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->devicePixelRatio() >= 2 ) {
>     imageVariant = "@2x";
> } else {
>     imageVariant = "";
> }
> ```

Forget the part about iOS - I think it's outdated, because it has applied to all platforms for a while now.

So in your case, you should add a splash@2x.png that is twice the resolution (and detail) of splash.png. If you're just using QPixmap, you will need to add the code above to ensure the correct image variant is selected. If you're using QML's Image type, it will select it automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I think It works. But I have another issue. I have updated the question.

Comment: Please ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565693/manage-multiple-displays