# Manage multiple displays

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QSplashScreen to display a splash screen for my QtQuick 2 application.

```
 QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
 QRect  screen_geometry = screen->geometry();
 int screen_width = screen_geometry.width();

 QPixmap pixmap("splash.png");
 QSplashScreen splash(pixmap.scaledToWidth(screen_width*0.35,Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```

screen_width is used to scale the image. My laptop is connected to a 2K monitor.

The issue is, the image is shown differently for different 'Display management options', such as

'PC only' , 'Duplicate Display' & 'Second screen only'.

My question is, how to manage both displays so that the image is displayed fine on both displays.

All I need is, display the splash screen with 35% screen width. 
It should be displayed with 35% screen width in both displays.

Comment: What do you intend by fine? Same size regardless of screen resolution or size?

Comment: Have you tried using [QDesktopWidget::screenNumber()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenNumber)?

Comment: question updated. I haven't tried  QDesktopWidget::screenNumber() yet.

Comment: I've noticed that `QDesktopWidget` is mostly deprecated, I suggest you use [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) instead, that represents a single phisical screen, you can get an instance with [QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop) and then get its geometry with [QScreen::geometry()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#geometry-prop). Let me know if that works so I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: I have already tried [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) before trying `QDesktopWidget `.
It is working. I can get primary screen. But I am unable to get secondary screen.

[QDesktopWidget::screenNumber()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#screenNumber) returns 0 in my case.

Comment: There is no secondary screen if you select 'Duplicate display' from window manager. The scaling is done by your OS.

Comment: @MartinHennings you are right. I realized that.

Comment: I have edited the question and changed almost everything. The old question may not be that helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the exact solution to my problem. But this is what I am doing, for the time being.

For this I need a secondary high resolution image 
say "splash@2x.png"

Refer: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html#loading-files-depending-on-platform

```
 QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
 QRect  screen_geometry = screen->geometry();
 int DPR = static_cast<int>(screen->devicePixelRatio()); // 1 or 2
 int screen_width = screen_geometry.width();

 QString splash_screen_image= "splash.png";

 if(DPR == 2)
 {
    //2K screen connected directly to PC
    splash_screen_image= "splash@2x.png";
    screen_width*=2;
 }

 if(DPR == 1 && screen_width >1920)
 {
    //'Second screen only' selected when laptop is connected to 2K display
    splash_screen_image= "splash@2x.png";
    screen_width*=2;
 }

 if(DPR == 1 && screen_width <=1920)
 {
    //'Duplicate display' or 'PC only' selected when laptop is connected to 2K display
    // or Desktop PC connected to HD monitor
    //Use "splash.png"
 }

 QPixmap pixmap(splash_screen_image);
 QSplashScreen splash(pixmap.scaledToWidth(screen_width*0.35,Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```